# how do I get the real tag's width after tag's container resize

Tags: javascript, width

When one elements is showed the width of next element is visually changed. But when I access to the `width` property it stays the same. Please consider this example http://jsfiddle.net/f8aeh1e5/2/. Click on link `Clock me` and `row1` will show up and `row1` will have smaller size.

```
$('.show-row1').click(function(){
    $('.row1').toggle();
    $('.width').html($('.row2').width());
})
```

width is always the same. Is it possible to get real size of the `row2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're floating your `.row1` div so it won't affect the DOM flow or container size, hence the size of `.row2` isn't actually changing.